# How to deal with VS solution wide NuGet packages not used in any project

Tags: .net, nuget, build-process, nuget-package-restore

What's the best way to deal with NuGet packages which will be used to build or develop a VS solution but not referenced directly in any project?

For example stuff like NUnit GUI, OpenCover, NAnt, ...
All these tools are needed to build the final product but do not need to be referenced from any project.
This is only required to work with the solution and in the build process but never used directly as a reference to any project in a solution.

I'm using the NuGet extensions of VS 2015 and also NuGet command line...

Comment: This is indeed a good question...

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why this question is downvoted but it is legit question.

Actually version 3 of NuGet silently dropped the support for solution wide packages. Now from version 3 onwards you **have** to add the package to some project to make upgrades/auto package restore work, unlike previous iterations where you could add a solution wide package.

Also, as far as the difference in version numbers, you might be referring to NuGet.CommandLine which is version 2.8.6. It is different from the VS extension.

See [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/986) for details.